# Eloquent how to join/relate a table that has been connected via model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i may be phrasing the question wrongly, but here's the rundown of what I'm trying to figure out.

Right now I have three Models, **User.php, Company.php and UserCompanies.php**. Bassically, each User from my users table has a company, from the company table, and they are linked via my usercompanies table, which holds the user_id and company_id. In my Model for **UserCompanies.php** I hae this,

```
class UserCompanies extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Use a centralized auth DB
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    protected $connection = 'mysqlauth';

    protected $table = 'user_companies';

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'company_id', 'status',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the user that owns the usercompanies.
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withTrashed();
    }

    /**
     * Get the company
     */
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class)->withTrashed();
    }
}
```

Now just say in my controller, I need to pass data that has Users and Companies, how do i do so?

```
/App/User::where('status', 'A')->get();
/App/Companies::where('status', 'A')->get();
```

//what do i do with UserCompanies, how do i link it together without using a foreach loop?

Comment: what's relationship between users and companies?

Comment: basically, a company can have many users, but a user only 1 company. so in the user table, we do not store company_id, thus we use the user_companies table for that. user_companies table, stores user_id and company_id

Comment: whynot put company_id in user table. the relationship is just one-to-many

Comment: wasn't me who built the db structure haha. and it's a bit too late to add that relationship now, as we have over tens of thousnds of rows now..

Comment: maybe you can change to: one user has one user_companies, one company has many user_companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a model just for the pivot table like UserCompanies to me is absurb. If it doesn't serve any other purpose than a relationship. Please don't do so.

Let's say we define the the relationship like those in User and Company models:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'user_companies')
    }
}

class Company extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_companies')
    }
}
```

Then you can get your desired users and companies using those conditions:

```
User::whereHas('companies', function ($query) {
    $query->wherePivot('status', 'A');
})

Company::whereHas('users', function ($query) {
    $query->wherePivot('status', 'A');
})
```